# Flipping 0's and 1's from a natural number

Tags: javascript, math, recursion, numbers, integer

I want to create a javascript function to flip 1's to 0's in a natural number and I'm out of Ideas to achieve this,
Actually, I had a couple of URL's, and I replaced all 0's from a query parameter with 1's and now I no longer know the original parameter value, because there were few 1's in the original parameter value and now both are mixed, so basically I screwed myself,

The only solution for me is to try flipping each 1 to 0 and then 0's to 1's and test each number as the parameter.

This is the parameter value (after replacing 0's with 1's)

11422971

using above input I want to generate numbers as follows and test each of these

11422970
10422971
10422970
01422971

As you can see only 1's and 0's are changing, the change according to binary,

Answer (score 1):

Each position in your string can be one of `n` characters:

- A `"0"` can be either `"0"` or `"1"`
- A `"1"` can be either `"0"` or `"1"`
- Any other character `c` can only be `c`

We can store this in an array of arrays:

```
"11422971" -> [ ["0", "1"], ["0, "1"], ["4"], ... ]
```

To transform your string to this format, you can do a `split` and `map`:

```
const chars = "11422971"
  .split("")
  .map(c => c === "1" || c === "0" ? ["1", "0"] : [ c ]);
```

Once you got this format, the remaining logic is to create all possible combinations from this array. There are many ways to do so (search for "array combinations" or "permutations"). I've chosen to show a recursive pattern:

```js
const chars = "11422971"
  .split("")
  .map(c =>
    c === "1" || c === "0" 
      ? ["1", "0"]
      : [ c ]
    );

const perms = ([ xs, ...others ], s = "", ps = []) =>
    xs 
      ? ps.concat(...xs.map(x => perms(others, s + x, ps)))
      : ps.concat(s);
      
console.log(perms(chars));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a number like a string, and after parse it, something like that

var number= "12551";
number= number.replace("1","0");

The result of number will be "02550"

after that parse number to int

Answer (score 0):

This will generate all permutations.

```js
const generatePermutations = (number) => {
  let digits = number.split('');
  
  // find out which digits can be flipped
  let digitPositions = digits.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    if (val === '0' || val === '1') acc.push(i);
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
  // we're going to be taking things in reverse order
  digitPositions.reverse();
  
  // how many digits can we flip
  let noBits = digitPositions.length;
  
  // number of permutations is 2^noBits i.e. 3 digits means 2^3 = 8 permutations.
  let combinations = Math.pow(2, digitPositions.length);
  
  let permutations = [];
  
  // for each permutation
  for (var p = 0; p < combinations; p++) {
    // take a copy of digits for this permutation
    permutations[p] = digits.slice();
    
    // set each of the flippable bits according to the bit positions for this permutation
    // i = 3 = 011 in binary
    for (var i = 0; i < noBits; i++) {
      permutations[p][digitPositions[i]] = '' + ((p >> i) & 1);
    }
    
    permutations[p] = permutations[p].join('');
  }
  
  return permutations;
};

console.log(generatePermutations('11422970'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your looking for a `recursive` approach:

```
function recursive(acc, first, ...rest) {
    if(!first) return acc;
    if(first == '0' || first == '1') {
        var acc0 = acc.map(x => x + '0');
        var acc1 = acc.map(x => x + '1');
        return recursive([].concat(acc0, acc1), ...rest);
    } else {
        return recursive(acc.map(x => x + first), ...rest); 
    }
}

recursive([''], ...'11422971')
// output ["00422970", "10422970", "01422970", "11422970", "00422971", "10422971", "01422971", "11422971"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This just counts in binary and fills out a template for each value.

```js
function getPossibleValues(str) {
    function getResult(n) {
        let nIndex = 0;
        const strValue = n.toString(2).padStart(nDigits, '0');
        return str.replace(rxMatch, () => strValue.charAt(nIndex++));
    }
    const rxMatch = /[01]/g;
    const nDigits = str.length - str.replace(rxMatch, '').length;
    const nMax = Math.pow(2, nDigits);
    const arrResult = [];
    for(let n = 0; n<nMax; n++) {
        arrResult.push(getResult(n));
    }
    return arrResult;
}

console.log(getPossibleValues('11422970'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all to respond, you saved my life, btw the approach I used was,

0- convert the number into a string. (so we can perform string operations like split())

1- count the number of 1's in the string (let's say the string is "11422971", so we get three 1's, I used split('1')-1 to count)

2- generate binary of three-digit length,(ie from 000 to 111).  three came from step 1.

2- break down the string to single chars, (we'll get 
array=['1','1','4','2','2','9','7','1'] )

3- take the first binary number (ie b=0b000)

4- replace first 1 from the character array with the first binary digit of b (ie replace 1 with 0), similarly replace second 1 with the second binary digit of b and so on.

5- we'll get the first combination (ie "00422970")

5- repeat step 3 and 4 for all binary numbers we generated in step 2.